# Brother Printer not in the CUPS list

Tags: pi-3, pi-3b+, printing, file-sharing, cups

I am using Raspberry Pi 3B+. I am making my printer - Brother DCP-T300 wireless using Raspberry Pi. But, I am not able to make it run.

In the option of choosing the make, Brother was not present.

So, I randomly chose HP, and then chose the model HP color Inkjet. It does not work.

I tried to find brother at other places, and tried to find it's PPD file, but I am not able to find it. It is not present on the official site of Brother.

What should I do? I am running test prints, but they are not being printed.

[image: Options to choose the model]

Comment: I found the PPD on brother website by searching for `cups ppd brother dcp-t300`

Comment: Hi, I am unable to find the ppd directly. I found the website from which you can create a brother ppd. Is that what you are referring to?

Comment: I found that in the downlaods of the brother website, there was cupswrapper package, i installed that, and now the printer's make, and model is visible. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Brother provides printer drivers for the x86 architecture, not for ARM. For the Pi, which is ARM, Brother does not provide printerdrivers.

You may have a look at https://github.com/alexivkin/brother-in-arms; maybe that helps.